# call a public function with another function in the same contract in solidity

Tags: function, call, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

what is the simplest solution to set up a function in a contract that automatically call a publish function of the same contract?

The basic structure is:

```
function send(uint256 value) public {
    address sender = _msgSender();
    }
```

I want to set up a function within the same contract that automatically makes a call trigger of the above public function when a specific wallet caller has a certain amount value.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the sender's balance by using the `balance` property of the `address` type.

```
function send(uint256 value) public {
    address sender = _msgSender();

    // this checks the sender's balance
    if (sender.balance >= 1 ether) {
        publish();
    }
}

function publish() public {
}
```

---

If you want to check how much they sent in the transaction executing your function, you can use the global variable `msg.value`.

Also, in order to accept the non-zero value, you need to make the function `payable`.

```
function send(uint256 value) public payable { // mind the `payable` keyword
    address sender = _msgSender();

    // this checks the value of this transaction
    if (msg.value >= 1 ether) {
        publish();
    }
}

function publish() public {
}
```

Comment: should it be ```this.publish();``` ?

Comment: @tomyhomie `public` functions can be called both internally (`publish()`) and externally (`this.publish()`).